# Do Racket streams memoize their elements?

Tags: stream, racket

Does Racket use memoization when computing large amounts of numbers from an infinite stream? So, for example, if I printed out (aka, computed and displayed) the first 400 numbers on the infinite stream of integers:
(1 2 3 ... 399 400)
And right after I asked to print the first 500 numbers on this infinite stream. Would this second set of computations use memoization? So the first 400 numbers would not be computed again?

Or does this functionality need to be coded by the user/obtained from libraries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The built-in [racket/stream](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-cons%29%29) library uses lazy evaluation and memoization to draw elements from a stream:

```
(require racket/stream)

(define (print-and-return x)
  (displayln "drawing element...")
  x)

(define (in-range-stream n m)
  (if (= n m)
      empty-stream
      (stream-cons (print-and-return n) (in-range-stream (add1 n) m))))

(define s (in-range-stream 5 10))

(stream-first s)
(stream-first s)
(stream-first (stream-rest s))
```

The expressions passed to [`stream-cons`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html?q=stream-cons#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-cons%29%29) are not evaluated until requested either with [`stream-first`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html?q=stream-cons#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-first%29%29) or [`stream-rest`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html?q=stream-cons#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._stream-rest%29%29). Once evaluated, they are memoized. Notice that despite the four stream operations performed on `s`, only two `"drawing element..." messages are displayed.

Comment: Oh! I've never tried `racket/stream`. Your answer is more specific to the original question. Up-voting.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `memoize` package.

GitHub source: https://github.com/jbclements/memoize/tree/master

`raco pkg install memoize`

Using it is as simple as replacing `define` with `define/memo`.  To quote its example:

```
(define (fib n)                                     
  (if (<= n 1) 1 (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))  

> (time (fib 35))                                   
cpu time: 513 real time: 522 gc time: 0             
14930352                                            

> (define/memo (fib n)                              
    (if (<= n 1) 1 (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))

> (time (fib 35))                                   
cpu time: 0 real time: 0 gc time: 0                 
14930352
```

---

Also, it is generally quite easy to implement memoization yourself using a Racket hash-table.

Answer (score 1):

For other Scheme implementations that use [SRFI 41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html) streams, those streams also fully memoise all the materialised elements.

In fact, in my Guile port of SRFI 41 (which has been in Guile since 2.0.9), the default printer for streams will print out all the elements so materialised (and nothing that isn't):

```
scheme@(guile-user)> ,use (srfi srfi-41)
scheme@(guile-user)> (define str (stream-from 0))
scheme@(guile-user)> (stream-ref str 4)
$1 = 4
scheme@(guile-user)> str
$2 = #<stream ? ? ? ? 4 ...>
```

Any of the elements that aren't being printed out as `?` or `...` have already been memoised and won't be recomputed. (If you're curious about how to implement such a printer, here's [the Guile version](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guile.git/commit/?id=b6e374e535597448cb09588300d76b5d270d5d3a).)