# Lazy stream of random(s): When does evaluation happen?

Tags: random, stream, scheme, racket, lazy-evaluation

The following code, I thought, should define a stream of random numbers between 1 and 10:

```
(define random-stream (stream-cons (random 1 11) random-stream))
```

However, what it *actually* does is define a stream of a specific random number. For example:

```
> (stream->list (stream-take random-stream 10))
'(5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5)
```

I presume this is the random number that `(random 1 11)` produces when the definition is first parsed. I got around this by making `random-stream` an argument-less function:

```
(define (random-stream) (stream-cons (random 1 11) (random-stream)))
```

This works:

```
> (stream->list (stream-take (random-stream) 10))
'(6 1 10 9 4 2 2 3 3 10)
```

So it looks to me that constants are, understandably, evaluated at read time, whereas functions are evaluated at call time. Usually this wouldn't matter, but in the case of a stream -- where you've got a recursive definition -- this makes a difference.

Is this how it works, or is it more subtle than this? Are there other cases one should be aware of regarding this difference?

Comment: Racket takes https://xkcd.com/221/ too seriously lol

Comment: But more seriously, I think this is due to memoization in stream. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26481874/718349.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `random-stream` an argument-less function is the correct solution.

```
(define (random-stream) (stream-cons (random 1 11) (random-stream)))
```

I will explain why.

When you define a stream normally with `(define my-stream (stream-cons ....))`, there is only one value for the stream. Any reference to `my-stream` will produce the same value.

```
(define my-stream (stream-cons (random 1 11) my-stream))
```

The `my-stream` inside the "rest" is literally the same value `eq?` to the one `my-stream`.

```
> (eq? my-stream (stream-rest my-stream))
#true
```

So because they are the same value, they can be substituted in function calls. If `(stream-first my-stream)` returns 5, then `(stream-first (stream-rest my-stream))` must also return 5. (This is because `stream-first` is a "pure" function in the sense that it returns the same output for the same inputs.)

```
> (eq? (stream-first my-stream) (stream-first (stream-rest my-stream)))
#true
```

This is not the case with the function version because every time the function is called it creates a new stream value.

```
(define (random-stream) (stream-cons (random 1 11) (random-stream)))

> (eq? (random-stream) (random-stream))
#false
> (eq? (stream-first (random-stream)) (stream-first (random-stream)))
#false
```

Since the "rest" field also calls `(random-stream)`, the rest is different from the whole.

```
> (define generated-stream (random-stream))
> (eq? generated-stream (stream-rest generated-stream))
#false
> (eq? (stream-first generated-stream) (stream-first (stream-rest generated-stream)))
#false
```

Comment: While it is true that `(eq? my-stream (stream-rest my-stream))`, I don't think it necessarily implies that "If ... returns 5, then ... must also return 5". `random` and `random` are `eq?` to each other, but `(random)` and `(random)` don't need to evaluate to the same value.

Comment: Okay, you're right, there's a hidden assumption that `stream-first` is a "pure" function in the sense that it returns the same output for the same inputs.

Comment: I have to specify what I mean by "pure" because it is _not_ "pure" in the sense of no-side-effects, but is "pure" in the sense of same-inputs-same-output.

Comment: perhaps `(random-stream)` is better named `(make-random-stream)`...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer that the problem with OP code is that `random-stream` is a stream for which `(stream-first random-stream)` is some random number, while `(stream-rest random-stream)` is also the same stream beginning with the same number.

I don't quite agree with "*an argument-less function is the correct solution*," though.

One alternative solution would be to use `stream-map` to map random numbers over the natural numbers:

```
(define random-stream/1-10
  (stream-map (lambda (x) (random 1 11)) (in-naturals)))
```

It would be even *better* to create a function that makes a stream of random numbers:

```
(define (random-stream a b)
  (stream-map (lambda (x) (random a b)) (in-naturals)))
```

This function can be used to create a stream (note that `in-naturals` is also a function that creates streams):

```
random_streams.rkt> (define my-stream (random-stream 1 11))
random_streams.rkt> (stream->list (stream-take my-stream 10))
'(1 1 2 7 5 7 4 2 2 9)
```

Using this idea of a function that *creates* streams, the `stream-cons` method can be rescued:

```
(define (random-stream-cons a b)
  (stream-cons (random a b) (random-stream-cons a b)))
```

When `stream-first` is called on a stream created with `random-stream-cons`, a random number is returned; when `stream-rest` is called on the same stream, another stream with a random number as its first element is returned.

The created streams are persistent:

```
random_streams.rkt> (stream->list (stream-take random-stream/1-10 10))
'(10 9 9 1 2 7 6 2 6 6)
random_streams.rkt> (stream->list (stream-take random-stream/1-10 15))
'(10 9 9 1 2 7 6 2 6 6 10 1 2 8 5)

random_streams.rkt> (define my-stream-1 (random-stream 1 11))
random_streams.rkt> (stream->list (stream-take my-stream-1 10))
'(1 4 1 10 7 9 9 9 2 9)
random_streams.rkt> (stream->list (stream-take my-stream-1 15))
'(1 4 1 10 7 9 9 9 2 9 2 3 9 9 10)

random_streams.rkt> (define my-stream-2 (random-stream-cons 1 11))
random_streams.rkt> (stream->list (stream-take my-stream-2 10))
'(10 4 6 1 4 2 10 5 3 6)
random_streams.rkt> (stream->list (stream-take my-stream-2 15))
'(10 4 6 1 4 2 10 5 3 6 1 5 7 5 5)
```

This `random-stream-cons/1-10` function is essentially the same as the earlier `random-stream-cons` function (but with no arguments); yet neither of them are *streams*. Both of them are functions that *create* streams:

```
(define (random-stream-cons/1-10) (stream-cons (random 1 11) (random-stream-cons/1-10)))
```

Each time that one of these stream creation functions is called, a new stream is returned:

```
random_streams.rkt> (stream->list (stream-take (random-stream-cons/1-10) 10))
'(10 8 3 10 8 8 1 8 4 5)
random_streams.rkt> (stream->list (stream-take (random-stream-cons/1-10) 10))
'(1 8 7 3 8 2 2 10 6 5)
```

This might be just what is desired; such functions are very useful, for example, in iteration contexts:

```
random_streams.rkt> (for ([x (stream-take (random-stream 1 11) 5)])
                      (displayln x))
2
8
9
1
3
```

So, functions that return streams are useful, and the resulting streams can be bound to a symbol if desired. For streams that may be needed multiple times with different values, arguments can be provided in custom stream-creation functions. But for one-off streams, `stream-map` already does the job of returning a stream which can be bound to a symbol just as OP had originally written.

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from the other answer. :) Arguments, no arguments, a function call is still a function call. Mapping a function over a stream will call that function for every element of that stream; and since the function ignores its argument, it's exactly like an argumentless call, semantically. One could make `(define infstream (stream-cons infstream infstream))` and map `(lambda (_) (whatever))` over *that*. And of course `((lambda (_) (whatever)) anything)` is exactly the same as `((lambda () (whatever)))`

Comment: @WillNess -- I think my answer places more emphasis on the distinction between functions that create streams and the streams themselves; the fundamentals of the answers are the same, but some might find an alternate useful. The `stream-map` version allows a pretty clean one-liner for assigning a one-off stream, as OP originally had, and is an alternative to defining a separate creation function. Certainly different syntax.

Comment: @WillNess --  I don't see any point in defining a new stream (as `infstream`) and then mapping over that, when you already have access to adequate streams with `in-naturals`. `(stream-map (lambda () (whatever)))` causes an arity-mismatch error.

Comment: good points in your first comment (and I've commented under the other answer in the mean time, to same effect). as for the second comment, `infstream` is O(1) memory; and the last bit in the 2nd comment deals with something I never wrote. :)